# SqlDataReader Get Value By Column Name (Not Ordinal Number)

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

Using the [methods of the SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I can get the value of a column by passing in it's ordinal, such as the value of the first column if I pass in `read.GetValue(0)`, or the second column if I pass in `read.GetValue(1)`.

In looking at the methods, I don't see an option to get the value of a column by passing in the name of a column, such as ColumnID. In my mythical example, I would want to pass in `read.GetValueofColumn("ColumnID")` and read the value in the column (**note that the method `GetValueofColumn` doesn't exist so far as I can tell from the method list**).

Am I missing the method to do this, or a way to do this?

Comment: Try "read.GetValue["ColumnName"]"

Comment: I've tried that and unfortunately `GetValue` only accepts an `int`.

Comment: why don't you just get the value you are looking for by the `dataReader["ColumnName"]` it's not that trivial.. here is a good site to keep in your arsenal [C# Get DataReader values by Column Name](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/ReferencedatainSqlDataReaderbycolumnname.htm)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can get the ordinal of the column by using the `GetOrdinal` method, so your call could be:

```
read.GetValue(read.GetOrdinal("ColumnID"));
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks; will accept when I can't (*can accept an answer in 8 minutes*?)

Comment: For performance reasons, Microsoft now recommends you call your GetOrdinal outside your read loop, and only call GetValue(int) inside the loop

Comment: great answer, however, using `read.GetFieldValue<YourType>(read.GetOrdinal("ColumnID"));` will save you the casting

Comment: Late to the game on this one. Just want to add that you should be careful if your select list columns use an AS clause to name columns with the same name. In this case the outer GetValue() call could end up getting you the value of a potentially different column.

Answer (score 38):

`Datareader` has numeric (position based) method, and a textual (field name based) one. So, with field name, you can get the value like

```
object value = reader["some field name"];
```

(assuming that `reader` is a `datareader`)

Comment: True, but the other helper functions to the reader only take an int, so if you want to use them, you have to call GetOrdinal (preferably outside the read loop) to get the index, and then you can call any of the functions (including reader[index]) inside the read loop .

Comment: The question is 'an option to get the value of a column by passing in the name of a column', and I suppose my answer is the most simple.

Answer (score 16):

Late answer, but...  This has always worked for me, and I think it is closer to what OP is trying to achieve:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn))
using (SqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

    if (rs.HasRows) {

        while (rs.Read()) {

            Meeting_DiscussionItems_MX di = new Meeting_DiscussionItems_MX();

            di._Discussion_Item_MX_ID   = (int) rs["Discussion_Item_MX_ID"];
            di._Meeting_ID              = (int) rs["Meeting_ID"];
            di._Discussion_Item_Name    = (string) rs["Discussion_Item_Name"];
            di._Display_Order           = (string) rs["Display_Order"];
            di._Status                  = (string) rs["Status"];
            di._Discussion_Items        = (string) rs["Discussion_Items"];
            di._ETOPS_Items             = (string) rs["ETOPS_Items"];
            di._Followup                = (string) rs["Followup"];
            di._Pinned                  = (string) rs["Pinned"];
            di._Active                  = (string) rs["Active"];

            _Meeting_DiscussionItems_MX.Add(di);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any downside to doing it this way?

Comment: Not for me, so far.  It does require checking for nulls, if nulls are possible in your columns, with DBNull.Value.

Answer (score 7):

For convenience you can add some helpers like this:

```
public static string GetString(this SqlDataReader reader, string name) {
    return GetFieldValue<String>(reader, name, (string)null);
}

public static T GetFieldValue<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string fieldName, T defaultvalue = default(T)) {
    try {
        var value = reader[fieldName];
        if (value == DBNull.Value || value == null)
            return defaultvalue;
        return (T)value;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //SimpleLog.Error("Error reading databasefield " + fieldName + "| ", e);
    }
    return defaultvalue;
}
```

As you can see it is the reader that allows to use fieldnames but it returns an object that needs to be casted to the right datatype. The extension takes care of both and adds a defaultvalue for when the field is null.

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(rdr["id"] + " -- " + rdr["time"]);
}
rdr.Close();
```

where `id` and `time` are column names

Answer (score 2):

you must use like below , replacing "(string)" by the type you must use for:

`(string) reader["name"];`